# Dispose chain subscribed on background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java2, thread-sleep

Chain subscribed on background thread is disposed. Than is called method `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` of `ExecutorService`. Flag interrupted of thread is set to **true**.

Is flag for signalization of interruption readed internally by Rx Operators or is ignored? When dispose is called than is only disable emmision to downstream? Is it a good choice to set the flag again to **true** in a catch block?

I try this for testing purposes:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> {
  log("section before sleep");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
  log("section after sleep");
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe();
```

**I dispose chain during sleep** and log with *"section after sleep is called"* is still printed.
I know that this code with native thread sleep is not clear. But I want to avoid switching threads (delay), it is overkill. Inner logic should not be broken because chain use own thread (usage IoSchedulder).

After call of dispose is still called entire block of fromAction operator?

Does this solution have any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @elnino for correcting me. The *io* scheduler will interrupt threads when cancellation comes from a different thread to the subscribed thread.

With regards to your code, the "section after sleep" log line will always get printed even if the thread is interrupted. Try this:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> {
  log("section before sleep");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    log("interrupted");
  }
  log("section after sleep");
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe();
```

If the disposal interrupts the thread then you should see "interrupted" and "section after sleep".

Comment: I use implementation for Android and I am sure that RxJava call internally ((NewThreadWorker)w).shutdown(). For IoScheduler is NewThreadWorker implemented as ScheduledExecutorService executor with one thread. Method shutdown of worker call executor.shutdown(). Result is call of method interrupt for Thread of Worker. It is contradiction with your answer. It means that RxJava interrupt thread on disposal.
What do you think your answer?

Comment: Does RxJava work with flag of interruption? Or is only finished planned work? Is good pattern set flag to true again? I want to send this question  to author of library. @DaveMoten

Comment: Why don't you just read the source or write some small tests? Have you stepped through using an ide that automatically downloads source code from maven Central? You really can answer your own question. From memory the ScheduledExecutorService returns a Future from a submit call and that Future can be cancelled with a Boolean parameter that indicates whether the thread should be interrupted.